# Kernel and image of a diagonalizable endomorphism $f$ given only an orthogonal basis$B={w_1,w_2,w_3}$, an eigenvalue, and that $f(w_1)=f(w_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be diagonalizable with $B$, basis of eigenvectors, such that $B={w_1,w_2,w_3}$, where $w_1=(1,2,0),w_2=(0,1,1),w_3=(0,1,-1)$. If we know that $3$ is an eigenvalue and that $f(w_1)=f(w_2)$, how do we find $Im(f)$, $Ker(f)$ and and the expression of $f(x,y,z)$?

Comment: There are several options and I don't think the given data in enough to determine $\;f\;$ . It could be $\;f(w_1)=f(w_2)=3w_2\,,\,\,f(w_3)=kw_2\,,\,\,k\in\Bbb R\;$ , with $\;\dim\ker f=2\;,\;\;\dim\,\text{Im}\,f=1\;$ , and we already have infinite examples.

Comment: What are your thoughts about this? Any attempts?

Comment: @mickep Sadly, I've no idea. I've never tackled an exercise like this.

Comment: By the way, the basis does not look orthogonal. Also, I suggest you to update your question according to what hjhjhj57 and Timbuc writes below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0\neq w_1-w_2\in\ker f$, the associated matrix of the transformation is singular, so at least one of its eigenvalues is $0$. Then you have two possibilities $f(w_1)=f(w_2)=0$, in which case $f(w_3)=3w_3$ or $f(w_1)=f(w_2)=3w_1=3w_2$, in which case $f(w_3)=0$

Since the second case is obviously not true, we need $f(w_1)=f(w_2)=0$ and $f(w_3)=3w_3$. Can you obtain the transformation explicitly with this?

By the rank-nullity theorem we get that $\dim\mathbb{R}^3=3=\dim \ker f+\dim \operatorname{im} f = 2+1$.

**Edit:** To explicitly compute the transformation consider any vector $(x,y,z)$ and express it in terms of your basis:
$$
(x,y,z) = a(1,2,0)+b(0,1,1)+c(0,1,-1).
$$
Then $$f(x,y,z) = f(a(1,2,0)+b(0,1,1)+c(0,1,-1)) = cf(w_3) = 3cw_3 = 3c(0,1,-1).$$

Comment: Read the comments: there are examples different from what you gave.

Comment: @Timbuc If $\{w_i\}$ is an eigen-basis this should work.

Comment: I think that in fact it doesn't matter what kind of basis we're given: with the data we have there are many examples of maps that fulfill the conditions.

Comment: @Timbuc Here's what I think: Since $f(w_i) = k_i w_i$, the only way the condition $f(w_1)=f(w_2)$ holds is if $k_1w_1 = k_2w_2 \iff k_1=k_2=0$ (since they are linearly independent). Then, by the other condition $f(w_3) = 3w_3$ and the transformation is completely determined.

Comment: Why "$\;f(w_1)=f(w_2)\implies k_1w_1=k_2w_2\;$" ? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Timbuc because $f(w_1) = k_1w_1 = f(w_2) = k_2w_2$.

Comment: Why would $\;f(w_1)=k_1w_1\;$?? I just can't see this, **unless** you understood from the problem's wording that $\;B\;$ is a basis of *eigenvectors* ...which could be, indeed. In fact, if this is so then the problem has, I think, solution.

Comment: @Timbuc That's what I said in my first comment. If this isn't the case the problem obviously can't be solved.

Comment: @h Oops. I missed that point! You're right then, but perhaps the OP can address these doubts.

Comment: @Timbuc He should! "*be diagonalizable with orthogonal basis*" isn't good enough :P

Comment: @h Indeed. In the meantime I'm upvoting your answer as I think now that *should* the interpretation of the OP's confusing wording. +1

Comment: Apologies for the confusion: your interpretation of the problem is correct and I edited the question now. Could you clarify why "the second case is obviously not true"?

Comment: @user62029 see my previous comment which stars "Here's what I think ...".